# UIButton not Responsive When placed out of its container UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uibutton

I have a UIScrollView. Inside this UIScrollView is a UIView which contains every other child views (including a UIButton). It has the same bounds as the UIScrollView.

I want:

1. The bottom of the UIScrollView is not scroll-able (where the UIButton is placed).
2. The UIButton is responsive.

So I set the bottom of the UIScrollView a little higher than the UIVIew as below image:

[image]

This will make the UIButton not responsive (it's responsive in the left layout). Any suggestion? Thanks!

Some part of my code:

```
self.scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
[self addSubview:self.scrollView];
self.scrollContent = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
[self.scrollView addSubview:self.scrollContent];

self.button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[self.scrollContent addSubview:self.button];
[self.button addTarget:self
                action:@selector(buttonPressed)
      forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Update:

Looks like the right way is to keep the bottom of the scroll view and set its contentSize, but since I'm using autolayout, I found that the height of the contentSize is always zero???

Comment: Looks like it doesn't work. Another issue is i have a button placed outside of  the scroll view initially. After I scroll it in, the button is also not responsive...

Answer (score 0):

You need to place the button in a view that is outside of the scroll views view hierarchy.

Currently the hit testing is failing because the button is outside of the scroll views bounds but within its hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

Add the button into scroll view after that try the below code:

```
self.scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    [self addSubview:self.scrollView];
    self.scrollContent = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:self.scrollContent];

        self.scrollView.delaysContentTouches = NO; //Add this line

    self.button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [self.scrollContent addSubview:self.button];
    [self.button addTarget:self
                    action:@selector(buttonPressed)
          forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```